# keep js function inside jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a menu class loading data from a received json file.

in the constructor I build the menu, so I have a for loop with this (extracted part) js:

```
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        var btn = $('<div>'+data[i].label+'</div>').appendTo(object.container);
        btn.click(function()
            {  
                if($('.blockingFrame').length == 0)//pas de blocking
                {
                    data[i].action()
                }
            });
    }
```

Now, obviously this doesn't work because on runtime data[i] doesn't exist anymore...
data[i].action contains a valid js function.

This works, but doesn't contains the condition..:

```
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        var btn = $('<div>'+data[i].label+'</div>').appendTo(object.container);
        btn.click(data[i].action);
    }
```

So I thought I could store this action inside the jquery object  and call it like this, but it doesn't work:

```
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        var btn = $('<div>'+data[i].label+'</div>').appendTo(object.container);
        btn.action = data[i].action;
        btn.click(function()
            {  
                if($('.blockingFrame').length == 0)//pas de blocking
                {
                    $(this).action();
                }
            });
    }
```

A partial solution I came u with, was to store the action in another event, like dblclick, and  trigger a dblclick inside the condition, but this seams ugly.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: About your attempt to create a method on the jQuery wrapper: jQuery doesn't use something like a lookup table to return objects of previously matched selectors, obviously because the DOM could change anytime and these wrappers would be obsolete then. So when you call `$(this)`, a new jQuery wrapper is created that does not have the `action` method set. Instead you should use `btn.data('action', data[i].action);` and call it later with `$(this).data('action')();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for` loops [don't work properly with closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). Consider using iterator methods instead:

```
$.each(data, function(index, elem) {
    var btn = $('<div>'+elem.label+'</div>').appendTo(object.container);
    btn.click(function()
        {  
            if($('.blockingFrame').length == 0)//pas de blocking
            {
                elem.action()
            }
        });
}
```

Iterators are usually more elegant and compact than `for` loops, especially when you have them nested.

The reason why your last snippet doesn't work if that `btn = $(...)` is a temporary jquery object and disappears once  you leave the scope, with everything you have assigned to it. When later a `click` handler is being invoked, you create a new jquery object via `$(this)`, which doesn't carry your changes from the previous step. If you want to keep any data attached permanently to an element, use the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method - but in this case there's no need for that.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.
I had imagined using the data attribute, but was unsure if it would accept functions...

Answer (score 1):

Use an immediately-executing function to create a closure that holds `i`.

```
for (var i = 0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var btn = $('<div>'+data[i].label+'</div>').appendTo(object.container);
    btn.click(function(i) {
        return function() {  
            if($('.blockingFrame').length == 0)//pas de blocking {
                data[i].action();
        }
    }(i));
}
```